# Angular KYC and KYB package suggestions

Tags: angular, verification

I want to integrate KYC and KYB in to my Angular application.

Which packages which has good documentation specifically for Angular would you suggest me?

Problem is, that I will be first time doing KYC and KYB verification and I am junior developer, so good documentation for Angular would be crucial for me.